# What Does Clear Do?

Tags: mysql-cli

Being used to Linux I typed `clear` into MySQL CLI and expected the screen to clear - it did not. But it didn't produce a syntax error or any other kind of notice.

I decided to type any random word into it

```
MariaDB [db_name] > trey;
```

This produced:

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'trey' at line 1

Which I kind of expected, but now it's making me worried that `clear` is doing something behind-the-scenes.

When I searched the webs for `MySQL clear man`, nothing came up. I'm not specifically asking how to clear the screen as I found SO posts detailing how-to, but what does `clear` do? And why doesn't it produce a syntax error?

Comment: `clear     (\c) Clear the current input statement.`- from https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-commands.html

Comment: @Jonnix tis the answer, primarily this bit: `If mysql is invoked with the --binary-mode option, all mysql commands are disabled except charset and delimiter`